# Display resource usage as a Gantt Chart-like plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm working with a distributed system which makes opportunistic use of connected resources. I would like to display the usage of the resources over time in a Gantt Chart-like plot, where resources are on the y-axis and time is on the x-axis. I would also like to display resources when disconnected (i.e., no horizontal bar), connected but not used (i.e., empty horizontal bar), and progressively used (i.e., horizontal bar partially or entirely filled depending on the resource usage on that particular machine).

I'm no pgfplots pro, so the question is: would something like this be possible? If not, does any of you have an alternative on how to display the usage of said resources over time in a similar way? I know the existence of `pgfgantt`, but I don't think that would help. In fact, by reading its doc it seems to me that I cannot really model the usage of each resource by partially filling the horizontal bar. I would like to be able to fill the bar horizontally, as depicted by the following figure badly hand-drawn on my wall:

[image]

R1 is the first resource used, and at the beginning only half of it is used (i.e., 2 cores out of 4). It then gets progressively filled with work, and the work then distributed on R2, which gets filled by half (because R1 cannot sustain it). R2 leaves the network and the work is migrated to R3. In the end R1 outsources part of its work on R4 too, resulting in the three of them having half their cores used. I do not think this type of filing can be achieved on `pgfgantt`.

Thanks for your time and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Why do you think `pgfgantt` won't help?

Comment: I've searched some examples online and I don't think I might use it the way I would like to. It doesn't look like I can do what I would like to do...

Comment: Based on your description of what you want so far, I think `pgfgantt` could do exactly what you want to do, so please edit the question to explain in detail why it doesn't work and/or to add an image of what you want.

Comment: Edited + added a picture to better explain what I mean.